# Jquery - selectors - Selecting every element within a div

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

Is there an easy way to select all elements within a div (or any other element) with `jQuery`?
I have been searching for hours this week and I will continue to bang my head against my keyboard.

```
<div class="Someclass">
    <img src="" title="" />
    <ul>
        <li></li>
        <li><a href="" alt="" /></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I want an easy way to select all elements within `.Someclass` without having to call out each element.

Comment: what do you mean by "select all elements" ? Something like `$('.Someclass').html()` or `$('.Someclass').find('img')` ?

Answer (score 16):

The easier jQuery only selection would be `$("#divID *")`. As you know in CSS `a b` means all `b` which is *descendant* of `a` and `a > b` means all `b` which is *direct child* of `a` so `#myDiv *` means everything that is a *descendant* of a `<div>` with `id="myDiv"`.

Comment: If I want to include the div in the selection then would the best way be $(#divID, #divID *) ?

Answer (score 6):

http://api.jquery.com/children/

```
$('div.someclass').children();
```

Comment: "Is there an easy way to select all elements within a div?"   "I want an easy way to select all elements within .Somclass ..." - why the -1?

Comment: Thanks guys! I stopped banging my head against the keyboard.

Comment: children() will only select children, not other descendants. It only goes one level down the DOM tree.

Answer (score 3):

To get all children and descendents:

```
$('.SomeClass *')
```

To get only direct children:

```
$('.SomeClass > *')
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want absolutely every element within .Someclass, use:

```
var allElements = $(".Someclass *");
```

Answer (score 1):

This works in Chrome:

```
$(".Someclass *").addClass("testing");
```

Answer (score 0):

or if you want everything not just direct children. `$('.someclass *')`