# Global AJAX event and function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I need to add a `class` on every element inside a `div` that is loaded by AJAX. However I want to do this globally, because I do not have access to a single AJAX call. I do not know the URL of where the response would be loaded.

I tried `ajaxStart` and `ajaxComplete` but I did not succeed with any of that. Can someone please suggest what is proper way to go? I do not need the whole code, just a suggestion what is proper way to do that. Thank you.

```
        $(document).ajaxStart(function() {
            $("*").addClass("someclass");   
        });
```

How can I change above code so that my selector is any element only inside div that is loaded by AJAX if I do not know which div that is?

Comment: `$.ajaxStart()`, `$.ajaxComplete()` or `$.ajaxSetup()` should work absolutely fine for your scenario. Please add the code that didn't work to the question so we can see if there's any issues with it. Please also check the console for errors

Comment: Thank you. I do not have any errors, I just can not figure out what is proper way to do that. If I do it with code I added, I will get class someclass to any element inside body, but I need it only on elements inside div that is loaded

Comment: you should do this on ajaxComplete and I think your problem is correct selectors.  I would use `$(".myClass *")` as your selector.  See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5306734/jquery-selectors-selecting-every-element-within-a-div) for an explanation